# How to manage Markers well using google maps api v2 on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, markers

I'm trying to implement app in which you can add your own marker which will be given a shutdown time. To do so I need to know how to manage my markers. Let's say I have array list of users with assigned unique ID.

```
    private ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I will create array list of markers which will contain information like Latitude, Longitude, Title, owner's ID and deadline.

```
    private ArrayList<MyMarker> mMarkersArray = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();
```

Next whenever user will activate add marker method, new marker will be pushed to my list of markers. Ideologically everything seems nice and easy, furthermore creating new object looks like this:

```
    Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() (...) );
```

but when it comes to managing specific markers it seems like I'm missing something. There will be some trigger method which will check the deadline of all markers (or rather first one on the 'sorted by deadline' list) and then it should remove (not hide, because I think it would be inefficient from the memory point of view). How to achieve this? I can't add some custom variable like ID to markers (so I could then find the one I'm interested in) and I'm a bit lost.

There is a way to achieve this by clearing whole map and then rendering again all markers except the inactive, but as far as I'm concerned it's very inefficient and there has to be better solution.

Comment: In java, you can not add a custom variable to an existing object. But you can make a custom Marker class by subclassing the Marker class, you read [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) about how to `extends` a class. Or, you can use `HashMap` to store your Markers instead of List. Each pair in the `HashMap`, you can set your Marker as `key`, and the deadline as `value`.

Comment: Let's say I found the interesting marker in my HashMap and I would like to remove it without clearing whole map and rendering all markers from HashMap (very inefficient). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a specific marker from the map, you can just call the [remove()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#remove()). method.

Sample code to remove a marker from MapView and HashMap:

```
 for (Marker marker : hm.keySet()) {
      if (hm.get(marker).equals(deadline)) {
        marker.remove();
        hm.remove(marker);
      }
  }
```

You dont need to clear the entire MapView, if you just call remove() method on specific marker.